# Highcharts legend position same as tooltip position or make tooltip still visible after hiden series

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

How I can set the position of legend exactly as the tooltip position? The tooltip position in original demo https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/stock-tools-gui is placed on the left top corner of yaxis each series.
And this position is dynamic after adding some indicator or change height of yaxis.

The possible way is to put series name directly to tooltip formatter function, but in this case I have an issue to set the series name still visible...because the tooltip is show base of visibility of series points.

Answer (score 2):

Are the standard options available from the API do not meet your requirements?
You can set this legend as you like from there: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend

```
 legend: {
   layout: 'vertical',
   align: 'right',
   verticalAlign: 'middle',
   itemMarginTop: 10,
   itemMarginBottom: 10
 },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hb7ncd5a/

Comment: Hi @madepiet, By this positioning,I don't know to add legend to position where I want.

Comment: It was just an example. You can manipulate these options and you can position this legend wherever you want: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bx51jk8y/

Comment: I dont know how to set dynamic yaxis for legend position. For example,when I add some new indicator in Highstock, the new yaxis will created and tooltip position is automaticly changed, this is happend due to below code. I would like to add this code to legend position as well.


`position = {
x: point.series.chart.plotLeft,
y: point.series.yAxis.top - chart.plotTop
};`

Comment: You can use the load event for this and programmable set these values: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tgd2ofnb/

Comment: Hi @madepiet, thank you for your suggestion, maybe could working, but I solve it through CSS. Thanks.